# sound control of two different swf files in a html page within two different object<> tag

Tags: flash

In a html page I've two `object<>` tags which contain back1.swf and back2.swf . Only back1.swf contain buttons and other is swf movie. One of the button is 'sound pause' button. Is it possible to control sounds the 2nd one swf movie? **Need for AS2.**

Two Object tags like `<object>...</object>` and
`<object>....</object>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Look up the LocalConnection class. Both swfs will need to implement this to communicate with each other. Can't find the AS2 reference right now, but I should be in the help api.